# How do I jump over the wide area in world 8-2?

Tags: super-mario-bros

Does anybody know how to jump over the wide area in Super Mario Bros. world 8-2?

In world 8-1, I managed to jump on the goombas but I can't do this in world 8-2 :( It just doesn't want to jump that far.

I'm playing the game on a NES emulator on Android. Could that be the reason?

Made a screenshot just as I am about to run an jump
[image: the gap]

Another one during jump
[image: the gap]
*Had to let go of the button to make the screen shot*

[image: the gap]
Here is the trajectory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have no idea how your Android App handles the jump, but if you want to make it, here's a step-by-step of what you need to do.

1. Stand on the far edge (left) of the pipe.
2. Hold down your run button, and do not let go of it at any point in time
3. Begin running forward.  If you are running, as you should be, you should run straight over the gap.
4. At the very edge of the gap, begin holding the jump button while continuously holding right.
5. At no point should you let go of this button.  At no point should you let go of the run button.  At no point should you stop moving right.  You must hold all three buttons and not let go at any point,

The longer you hold both buttons, the further your jump will take you.  By following these steps, especially the last one, you should be able to make this difficult jump.  Do not worry about overshooting it. There's no danger there.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though youtube has a [walkthrough](http://youtu.be/YCIO3KEiUB0?t=17s).

It seems that if you get on that little platform just before the two column blocks you can jump (be sure to hold it down the entire jump) and then you'll be able to make it and complete the level.

Also, Mario is one of those, If at first you don't succeed games. Remember that you can save and load at a whim nowadays.

Comment: It doesn't work I saw that video before. Also noticed that at the end that Mario jumps way to far. With mine I can barely get the 400 flag. I think something is wrong with my game :(

Comment: It should be the same, I'll try to re-enact on my own but I think it might be the emulator causing the shorter jump. (It could only register a semi-long button press before the android os registers a long-press)

Comment: You're supposed to do a *running* jump - when running, Mario will go straight over the 1-block gaps, allowing you to gain enough forward momentum to clear the large gap.

Comment: I know and I'm doing that. I'm jumping from the edge of the last block but it doesn't work sorry :(